# Will ResultSet be updated with the underlying database?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, resultset

Before I explain my problem I would like to say that I know the basics of JDBC but not really used to it.

I am using an updatable result set to hold data from 2 different tables, as in the following sample code:

```
searchQry = "SELECT ct.CustomerName, ct.Email, ct.PhoneNo, ot.ItemName 
                     FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE ct JOIN ORDER_Table ot 
                     ON ct.OrderID = ot.OrderID";
prestmt = dbcon.prepareStatement(searchQry, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
uprs = prestmt.executeQuery();
uprs.updateLong("ut.PhoneNo", 7240987456L);
uprs.updateString("otItemName", "GTA5");
uprs.updateRow();
```

I would like to know if I will update the database from somewhere else (not using the same result set object) while the result set, `upsr`, connected to the database, whether `uprs` will get updated with it or it will throw an error or it will go with the old data itself. Sorry if it a newbie question but I can't really test that on my DB without knowing the outcomes and safe measures.

Please, suggest me if there is any better way to update the underlining db along with the data in the ResultSet without having any transaction issues when changing from different places.

Using:
Oracle Database for JDBC connection.

Comment: You're touching on _isolation_ levels of a database transaction.  If you want to ensure that no one else can come in and do DML stuff between when you execute your query and perform the updates, then you probably want a serializable transaction.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I will keep that suggestion.

Comment: It depends, on the database, on the driver, on the isolation level, the type of change. For example `TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` would do that, but as most databases don't actually support it (fully), it will probably have been downgraded to `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`, etc.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that's a good information and I am using Oracle Database. I will be adding that to the question for others.